# can I create eth receive address using createAccountAddress function with api?

Tags: coinbase-api

I am writing a `script` which should generate new `coinbase eth address`. When I try `createAccountAddress` function it seems only creating address for btc. Any help regarding how to create eth address with this function

```
$address = new Address([
'name' => 'my address'
]);

$add = $client->createAccountAddress($account, $address);
```

Comment: Please update if u got success, I am keep trying to use createAccount via NodeModule, callback is returning null and the account is not getting created.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the requested code to get ETH Address
Dnt forget to Put your api key, secret , and ETH account id

Enjoy

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Coinbase\Wallet\Client;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Configuration;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Address;
use Coinbase\Wallet\Resource\Account;

$configuration = Configuration::apiKey('Enter Api Key','Enter Api Secret'); //update ur key and secrete
$client = Client::create($configuration);
$accountId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";  //Put Etheruem Account Id Here / You can get it by going to coinbase or calling get account here by api

$account = $client->getAccount($accountId);


$address = new Address([
'name' => 'New Address'
]);


$add = $client->createAccountAddress($account, $address);
$addressId = $client->getAccountAddresses($account);
$addresses = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $addressId->getFirstId());
$addo = json_encode($addresses->getAddress());
$addoo = str_replace('"', "", $addo);
echo $addoo;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this thread is quite old, but the api version is (afaik) the same in use today.  I do not have enough reputation points to reply.

The previous answer has a potential race condition if this is used where multiple people can be accessing at the same time such as on a web server.  Depending on how the address is used payments could be confused.

To correct this problem replace the last bit

```
$add = $client->createAccountAddress($account, $address); 
$addressId = $client->getAccountAddresses($account); 
$addresses = $client->getAccountAddress($account, $addressId->getFirstId()); 
$addo = json_encode($addresses->getAddress()); 
$addoo = str_replace('"', "", $addo); 
echo $addoo;

?>
```

with

```
$add = $client->createAccountAddress($account, $address); 
echo $add->getAddress();

?>
```